# Is it possible to program an autoclicker that stops when the user MANUALLY clicks the left button?

Tags: c++, winapi

Currently, I am attempting to program an autoclicker that stops when the user manually clicks the left button.

```
int main() {
    while(true) 
    {
        Sleep(10); 
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0 ,0); 
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0 ,0);  
        Sleep(200); 

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) 
        {
            exit(0); 
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

As I suspected, the program stops after the first click (from the autoclicker). Is there a way the program can differentiate a click from the autoclicker and the user?

Comment: @Frank  ty, forgot

Comment: If you check the MSB of the return value from `GetAsyncKeyState()` it will tell you if the key is down _currently_.

Comment: I once  saw an autoclicker in "The Simpsons" when Homer "optimized" its home-office work. In his case, it ended up with the explosion of the nuclear powerplant...

Comment: @EricKo Try simulate auto-click with your own method. For exit use standard.